# How to filter two different columns values together in filter query Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, filter, django-views

I have two columns,

For single amount value `amount` and for range amount values `amount_min` and `amount_max`

| amount | amount_min | amount_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25000 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 100000 | 300000 |

Using the following query,

```
Jobs.objects.filter(Q(created_on__gte = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)),Q(amount__range=(100000, 300000)) | Q(amount_min__gte = 100000, amount_max__lte = 300000))
```

Following is the observed output,

| amount | amount_min | amount_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25000 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 100000 | 300000 |

However the expected output should be,

| amount | amount_min | amount_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100000 | 300000 |

Can anyone please help me in this query ?

Comment: please share the error trackback too..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to combine the conditions with OR operator (|).

Give this a try:

```
from django.db.models import Q
import datetime

Jobs.objects.filter(
    created_on__gte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30),
    Q(amount_min=0, amount_max=0) |
    Q(amount_min__gte=100000, amount_min__lte=100000, amount_max__gte=300000, amount_max__lte=300000) |
    Q(amount__range=(100000, 300000))
)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for a quick reply. But using Q, when I try adding other filter conditions with it, I am facing Syntax error.

Comment: ```
Jobs.objects.filter(created_on__gte = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30),Q(amount_min__gte = 100000, amount_min__lte = 100000, amount_max__gte = 300000, amount_max__lte = 300000) | Q(amount__range=(100000, 300000)))
```

Comment: please update the post with your query and the error trackback you got.

Comment: Thanks I understood that why it was showing error, I just added Q() on other conditions with that and it started working. One issue I am still having is using the query that you have mentioned, I should get only second record ? but I am getting both the records can you tell me why ?

Comment: sorry didn't understand, you always want second record? or do we have to add some other filters? if so what is the condition?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant to say that the amount_min and amount_max in the second row in the table matches with the condition. However the first row in the table doesn't match to the query. right ? But yet it's showing me both the rows in the result.

Comment: please check the updated anser

Comment: Still same result coming. When I try to get the result in between 100000 - 300000 then I should get only second record but using the above query I am getting even the first row (ie., 25000 which is not in the range of 100000 - 300000 )

Comment: please edit your question and show the result, also expected result

Comment: I have updated the question, please check now

Comment: Using the query that you have mentioned in your answer, I am getting the observed output which doesn't not meet my requirement. I have updated the question. Have you checked ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your running into issues with **Q** because it doesn't like being combined with normal named arguments

Named argument example: `created_on__gte = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)`

What I personally do is **over-wrap** Q statements and be very deliberate, ex:

```py
Jobs.objects.filter(
    Q(created_on__gte = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
    & Q(
      Q(
          Q(amount_min__gte = 100000)
          & Q(amount_min__lte = 100000)
          & Q(amount_max__gte = 300000)
          & Q(amount_max__lte = 300000)
      )
      | Q(amount__range=(100000, 300000))
    )
)
```

Overkill?- Probably.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still same result coming. When I try to get the result in between 100000 - 300000 then I should get only second record (in the table) but using the above query I am getting even the first row with second row (ie., 25000 which is not in the range of 100000 - 300000 )

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how the original query parses `&` `|`, so I wrapped it again to be even more deliberate. My assumption tho is that it's hitting the `amount_min` and `amount_max` stuff